# word meaning "appearing synthetic"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for examples of single words which mean: having the appearance of being synthetic/man-made, as opposed to natural.

Example sentence:
After crossing the stream, they stumbled upon a _____ rock formation."

The meaning should be that they found a rock formation which may or may not have been man-made, but appeared to be (presumably because of it's apparently careful arrangement).

Comment: How about **faux** leather? Oh, no: it's intended to look real. How about **tacky**?

Comment: faux leather is definitely synthetic.  Tacky is a special property that some synthetic things have.

Here is an example sentence:
"After crossing the stream, they stumbled upon a _____ rock formation."

So they found a rock formation which may or may not have been man-made, but appeared to be (presumably because of it's apparently careful arrangement).

Comment: The title says "*appearing* synthetic" so I ruled out "faux leather" and "creme egg". Sadly **tacky** can be a property of real things.

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/488719/edit) the new information into the question?

Comment: What about artificial?

Comment: @LucianSava Just saw your comment - great minds think alike!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest **unnatural**. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unnatural) defines it:

> not being in accordance with nature or consistent with a normal course
>   of events

Comment: This fits what I asked for.  (Of course I'd still be interested in more examples).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend **artificial**

> Made or produced by human beings rather than occurring naturally, especially as a **copy of something natural.**

The 'natural copy' part seems a perfect fit re your rock formation example.

[From Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/artificial)

Alternatively, there's **bogus**

> Not genuine or true (used in a disapproving manner when deception has been attempted)

[Same source.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bogus)

Comment: The problem I have with these is that they only apply if the thing is actually man-made or synthetic.

I want an adjective that captures that an object "appears" man-made, regardless of whether or not it actually is.

Comment: @wes In my opinion, this is too narrow a query - a word for something 'appearing' man-made, but not necessarily.  If needs be couldn't you write exactly that - ***Appearing** man-made...*.  This exact example is seen following [a Google Books search](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rxSjKHkZvQ0C&pg=PT17&dq=%22appearing+man-made%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4zKaL9_DgAhU3QxUIHSMEDkMQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=%22appearing%20man-made%22&f=false) - in particular, *On Agression* by Konrad Lorenz: "*At intervals are loggerhead sponges, manbroad and tablehigh, almost appearing **man-made**...*"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you'll be able to find a single word, but you could say "uncannily-arranged" or "curiously structured".

It's more of a stretch, but you might also find "pareidolic" appropriate, pareidolia being the phenomenon where we perceive a familiar structure in a more random input.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareidolia